# Fetch changed data for table in Oracle Database to csv

Tags: sql, oracle

- **I Need to** fetch the changed data for table in oracle. Need help with the `sql query` which will fetch only the changed data for every 20 mins.
- Or is there another workaround for this where we can fetch changed data?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to detect "only changed data" - I presume you must have some kind of a "timestamp" column - then that would be

```
select columns
from your_table
where timestamp_column >= sysdate - 20/(24*60);
```

because of this: 20 minutes / (24 hours in a day * 60 minutes in an hour)

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate right_now,
  2         sysdate - 20/(24*60) twenty_minutes_ago
  3  from dual;

RIGHT_NOW           TWENTY_MINUTES_AGO
------------------- -------------------
24.10.2019 08:40:18 24.10.2019 08:20:18

SQL>
```

How to create a CSV?

**One option** is to store your query into a .SQL file and use operating system's Task Scheduler (for MS Windows) or cron (for Unix) or whatever your operating system is. Let the script **spool** the result. There are numerous SQL*Plus `SET` options you can use to make the output pretty; for example:

```
set termout off 
set trimspool on 
set echo off 
set verify off 
set autoprint off 
set serveroutput off 
set arraysize 1000 
set pagesize 0
set linesize 100
set long 10000
set numwidth 10
set feedback off
set colsep ';'
col empno format 99999
col ename format a10
col sal format 999G990
spool emps.txt
select empno, ename, sal from emp
where timestamp_column >= sysdate - 20/(24*60);
spool off
```

---

**Another option** is to create a stored procedure which will use `UTL_FILE` package and create that file in a directory (you'll have to talk to your DBA about it; it is - usually - on the database server; DBA should create a *directory* (as an Oracle object) and grant read/write privileges to you).

Then you'd create a database job (using `DBMS_JOB` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER` packages), scheduling it to run every 20 minutes.

---

Maybe the first one is simpler to implement; if nothing else, CSV is created on your local computer, not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need a last_updated column of type datetime/date in your table. Then to get updated in last 20 minutes, the query can become like below.

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.last_updated >= sysdate - 20/(24*60)
```

where t is your tablename and last_updated is last updated datetime.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a way to detect when rows change within the table then you can use a [flashback query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS1008) on your database (if it is set up to support it).

To get the new/modified rows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MINUS
SELECT *
FROM   table_name AS OF TIMESTAMP( SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '20' MINUTE )
```

and to get the deleted rows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name AS OF TIMESTAMP( SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '20' MINUTE )
WHERE  primary_key_column NOT IN ( SELECT primary_key_column FROM table_name )
```